# Docker registry-mirrors doesn't work from windows terminal

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I'm trying to set a custom `registry-mirrors` for Docker on a Windows 11 machine. I have tried all of below methods, but none of them make any change.

Method 1. Trying to set `registry-mirrors` in docker desktop:
[image]
This method changes `registry-mirrors` in docker desktop, but not affect on using docker through terminal.

Method 2. Trying to add `registry-mirrors` by setting this config:

```
"insecure-registries": [
  "https://docker.arvancloud.ir"
],
"registry-mirrors": [
  "https://docker.arvancloud.ir"
]
```

I have added above config to all these files one by one:

```
C:\Users\Javad\.docker\daemon.json

C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json

C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\windows-daemon-options.json

C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\linux-daemon-options.json
```

I have added `registry-mirrors` to all of above files, but I still get this error, while trying to pull some images:

```
PS C:\Users\Javad> docker run my-hello-arvan
Unable to find image 'my-hello-arvan:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/my-hello-arvan/manifests/latest": dialing registry-1.docker.io:443 with direct connection: connecting to 34.205.13.154:443: dial tcp 34.205.13.154:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

As you can see, it's still looking for `my-hello-arvan` in `registry-1.docker.io` instead my own register (`https://docker.arvancloud.ir`). Have you any idea what did I miss?